Oracle Apex 22.1 Unable to change column type from pop up lov to text
I have an existing interactive grid..
Select emp_id,deptname,dept_no,emp_name from employees;
Here Deptname was first a pop-up lov but now i need to change it to text field. As i change it to text and save i get the following error:
Column->DEPTNAME->Enable User to-> Sort
Component has been changed by another user and this attribute no longer exists. Please reload the page.
I try reloading and saving again but same issue.
Any suggestions?

Maybe try to set those attributes to off for the popup lov column, then saving and then changing to text ?
